# Yowsup installation missing connectionmanager.py

Tags: python, yowsup

It seems that I cannot get yowsup properly installed under Windows 7.

I am following these procedures for installation:
https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/blob/master/README.md

doing a

```
pip install yowsup2
python setup.py install
```

I have omitted installation of zlib since I do know where the dll is, 
but not in which directory I should copy it.

Everything runs fine when using yowsup-cli, I can send and receive messages.

However, I cannot run samples on signals and methods such as shown:

https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/wiki/%5BLegacy%5D-Yowsup-Documentation

since I cannot find the file connectionmanager.py, this is not installed or created.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I have meanwhile found that there is a connectionmanager.py in the "legacy package" instead of the "master package" which I can download from here:
https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/archive/legacy.zip

Comment: However, I do not get this legacy package installed. Executing 'Executing 'pip install -r requirements.txt' in the temporary directory where I downloaded the zip file to wroks but did not help

Comment: I seem to not understand the difference between the legacy and the master package, whether they need to be installed both, and how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

There are two branches: legacy (yowsup) and master (yowsup2)
Yowsup2 is the newer version with a clean up of the code compared to yowsup(legacy).
What you did is installing yowsup2 but you tried to use functions of the legacy package. (Imagine an old car as legacy without automatic but you trying to use it)
Also Yowsup2 (master) will get updates and that stuff while legacy won't be updated anymore.

If you have any more questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one needs to do an additional

```
pin install Yowsup
```

(mind the capital letter, and no trailing '2' here)

to install the legacy package which includes the connectionmanager.py

However, this is installed in the directory yowsup starting with a small 'y', but modules in the scripts are still not found since they refer to a Yowsup directory with capital Y.

Confused.

Comment: I am meanwhile no longer sure whether the connectionmanager.py is  functionality,which is supposed to work with the actual yowsup version, or whether it is out of date.